# Multi dimensional Arrays, in classes - Class Redifintion

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array

Im trying to process a multidimensional array in class and I keep getting: "ClassName" class type redefinition. I know multidimensional array's require statics for the array definitions. I believe my problem relates to that. However, I'm not sure how resolve it.

Can someone help me?

The .h File

```
    class Coordinates
    {
    public:
       int fillArray(int , int , int[6][2]);
       void processArray(int , int, int[6][2]);
    };
```

the .ccp file

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Coordinates.h"

    int Coordinates::fillArray(int m, int n, int ar0[6][2])
    {
   cout << "Enter the first value followed by the second value" << endl;
   // fills the array
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
    {
      for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) //This loops on the columns
      {
        cout << "Enter the Value: ";
        cin >> ar0[i][x];       // actual input
      }
   }
   }
```

Code Using it

```
    int main()
    {
     int locArray[6][2] = {};                   //new array for coordinates

     Coordinates coord;                         //new coordinate object

     coord.fillArray(6, 2, locArray);           //fill the coordinates
     coord.processArray(6, 2, locArray);            //process the information

      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Then the error is still not matching, your code is syntactically correct. Post the code using it, too.

Comment: Specificity the error is: "Coordinates" class type redefined. the error is coming from the class header file.

Comment: You are probably including `Coordinates.h` twice somewhere.

Comment: I'm very inexperience when it comes to multidimensional arrays. I could pull the fill array to the main program and process it with the class.

Comment: What leads you to believe it has anything to do with multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: I think it has to do with the multi - array due to have to have predefined constants to initialize a multi-array in c++

Comment: Im confused on how you see the trace working for the array? If i move the code to the main program it fills the array and reads values the way i see the trace working. So now im curious.

Comment: @AndrewBodin My bad, right you are.

Comment: Wee bit of undefined behaviour here: `return ar0[6][2];`both indexes are out of range.

Comment: I was "trying" to use that to return the value from the function. We can pull that out since were passing the actual array to the function.

Comment: @AndrewBodin So remove all the multi-dimensional arrays and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @juanchopanza If i move the (fillArray(int m, int n, int ar0[6][2])) function to the main program it works without errors.